# How do I search for a list of values in another PowerShell list and extract the relevant rows?

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, using the list of usernames in $secondlist, how do I search for these usernames in $list, extract only the rows that contain the same usernames in $secondlist, and produce $newlist?

$list:

```
| Name   | Manager | Username |
| ------ | ------- | -------- |
| Kumar  | Polly   | Kumar.A  |
| Ginny  | Bertha  | Ginny.P  |
| Adam   | Sam     | Adam.r   |
| Olivia | John    | Oliv.e   |
| Ria    | Edwin   | Ria.k    |
| Wayne  | Sid     | Wayne.g  |
| Greg   | Joel    | Greg.s   |
| Fion   | Beston  | Fion.w   |
| Sandy  | Matt    | Sandy.k  |
```

$secondlist:

```
| Username |
| -------- |
| Kumar.A  |
| Ginny.P  |
| Oliv.e   |
| Wayne.g  |
| Sandy.k  |
```

$newlist:

```
| Name   | Manager | Username |
| ------ | ------- | -------- |
| Kumar  | Polly   | Kumar.A  |
| Ginny  | Bertha  | Ginny.P  |
| Olivia | John    | Oliv.e   |
| Wayne  | Sid     | Wayne.g  |
| Sandy  | Matt    | Sandy.k  |
```

I came up with the following as a start:

```
script: |     
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
       [array]
       $list,
       [array]
       $secondlist
   )


   foreach ($item in $list) {     
       $username = $item.Username     
       $manager = $item.Manager  
       $name = $item.Name  
   } 
   foreach ($item in $secondlist) {     
       $newusername = $item.Username 
   }

 parameters:
   list: "{{ list }}" 
   secondlist: "{{ secondlist }}"
```

Comment: Isn't `$list | Where Username -in $secondlist.Username` working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter any list with [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3) operator.

For your example, I assume that `$list` and `$secondlist` are arrays of objects. So you can do:

```
$list | Where Username -in $secondlist.Username
```

#### How does it work?

One of many [Where-Object parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#parameters) is name of field by which you are filtering (`Username` in this case), then operator ([`-in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3#-in) which checks whether value is inside list of given objects).

`$secondlist.Username` is shortcut for getting values of `Username` property of all objects in `$secondlist`. This is called [Array properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays?view=powershell-7.3#array-properties) in docs.

#### Performance

If `$secondlist` is huge and you'd like to optimise, you could use [.NET HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) inside your script. Like this:

```
$usernameSet = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$secondlist.Username
$list | Where Username -in $usernameSet
```